# Renaming runtimeconfig.json Files

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I am using dotnet CLI with .NET Core 3.1 on my Mac.
I want to rename the auto-generated `*.runtimeconfig.json` files in the output/publish directories to some custom file names.

Is there a way to achieve such thing from the `project.csproj` file configuration?

Comment: `*.runtimeconfig.json` file is optional and user editable and, afaik, it's produced by `dotnet publish` command. Why do you need to rename it? You can have a look at some details [here](https://github.com/stuartleeks/dotnet-cli/blob/master/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md)

Comment: It gets produced by dotnet build and I still need it, otherwise I get errors when running my program. I do not like the name and I am wondering if I can configure the project.csproj to give it a different name?